# Can I use old sets of magic cards in an EDH deck

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have all sorts of old magic cards, for example m12, X ,vintage, m13, I'm just curious if I can add any of these cards to my Commander deck that I have now ,or would it be illegal??

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use any cards you could in Vintage (except for the banned list).

See [the rules on mtgcommander.net](http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php):

> Commander is played with vintage legal cards, with some exceptions:
>
> - cards are legal as of their set's prerelease
> - The following is the official banned list for commander games. These cards (and others like them) should not be played without prior agreement from the other players in the game.
>   ...[banned list]...

It'd be pretty silly to have to build 100-card decks with limited colors without being able to use a nice large card pool! And if you look at commander deck lists people have published online, it should be pretty clear that a lot of the really popular cards are old ones. (Not that M12 and M13 are really that old...)

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that commander is a casual format. So the ban list is nothing more than a suggestion of cards to avoid for the games to be enjoyable. If your playgroup thrives on playing degenerate combo commanders then by all means ignore the ban list. It is not like anyone should tell you what to play in casual formats.